# Synchronisation between sqlite and mysql

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have an app that stores locally some data in **sqlite**, 
I have a server that stores the same data in a **mysql** database,

Both tables have a **timestamp** column that indicates the time it was edited.

What i want to do is sync the data so it matches,
    So if another devices changes the central data on the server, it is pushed down to all devices.

Currently i achieve this by ...

In the app i store the time i last made a server read. 
I ask the server for all data that has changed since ...

I make a read about every 30 seconds

My issue, what happens when the clocks change (this will potentially cause issues)

What is the standard way of achieving what i want, the project is very early in development so i can change if there is a much better way of achieving that i want.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe just save the server timestamp on the client when doing an update

Comment: *when the clocks change* ... this is why you always, always, always use UTC as your time zone, converting to local values as needed for display purposes.  (I had a customer once insist that my FTP server clock should be set to "local time."  I told them the server was in [Greenwich](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time).)